# Problem separating js out from an svg file

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg file which is almost entirely made up of a script. I'd like to separate the script out, so that I can run it through a compressor, but I can't find a way to do this. Any help gratefully appreciated.

The svg file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg id="chart"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     onload="init(evt)" >

<script type="application/ecmascript">
<![CDATA[
...lots of code
//]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

What I've done is extracted out "lots of code" as lotsOfCode.js, and changed the svg file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg id="chart"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     onload="init(evt)" >

<script type="application/ecmascript" src="lotsOfCode.js">
</script>
</svg>
```

However, this doesn't work. The browser complains that it can't find the onload 'init' function. Any ideas? Do I have to do something to tell the browser that 'init' is in 'lotsOfCode.js'?

Thanks -

Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `xlink:href` instead of `src`:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="lotsOfCode.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** You'll also need to reference the `xlink` namespace:

```
<svg id="chart"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     onload="init(evt)" >
```

Comment: This produces an error: "namespace prefix xlink for href on script is not defined".

Comment: @user7 - Add a reference to the namespace in your `<svg/>` element.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent - that did it. Thanks. Any particular reason that you changed 'application' to 'text'?

Comment: @user7 - No reason - it was copy and paste from my own code and I didn't catch that you had a different `type`.  I'm not sure if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gillys answer, have you tried moving the script include to go before the svg line?

Like this:

```
<script type="application/ecmascript" src="lotsOfCode.js">
</script>
<svg id="chart"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     onload="init(evt)" >
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work either. The problem is that the svg document now contains two top-level elements: an svg and a script, and the browser complains that the second tag is beyond the end of the document.

Comment: That's not valid XML, but if the svg is inline in an html document then it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg id="chart"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     onload="init(evt)" >
<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="lotsOfCode.js"></script>
   <circle id='BlueCircle' cx='25' cy='25' r='20' style='fill:blue; '/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Important Note:
introducing in sequence, after <svg...>:
<script...>
...........
..........
svg objects
...........
</ svg> closing

Save the file with the extension *. Svg